# sequential numbers in a string to an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that has sequential numbers such as the following:

```
1. this is some text 2. this is more text 3. this is even more text
```

I'd like to split this into an array that starts with the numbers:

```
['1. this is some text', '2. this is more text', '3. this is even more text']
```

I tried the following:

```
string.split(/(?=\d[.][ ])/g);
```

This works well when the numbers are 1-9. However, when the numbers >=10, it doesn't work well.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is all you need to change (try on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k92px4gu/6/)):

```
string.split(/(?=\b\d+[.] )/g);
```

The `+` after the `\d` tells it to match 1 or more.

**EDIT:** The `\b` is a word boundary to ensure you're getting the number from the beginning, not each separate digit.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. 9 works fine, but it splits 10 like this: [...,'9. text goes here', '1', '0. the text for ten goes here', '1', '1. the next for eleven goes here']

Comment: @Marc: sorry about that, but the `\b` word boundary check I just added should do the trick.